# Insert Footnote with phpword

Tags: phpword

I am trying to insert a footnote in my generated document with phpword.
Assume this:

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$content= "Line\r\nAnother Line\r\nYet another [and my footnote] line\r\nfinal line";
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$textlines = preg_split("/(\r\n|\r|\n)/", $content);
foreach($textlines as $line) {
    $section->addText(htmlspecialchars($line));
}
```

And now I would like to have the text inside the brackets "[]" inserted as a footnote. I have NO idea how to get this handled. Maybe you understand this here: 
http://phpword.readthedocs.org/en/latest/elements.html#footnotes-endnotes

Answer (score 0):

Ok, did it myself. But it doesn't mean it is foolproof:

```
$content = "Line\r\nAnother Line\r\nYetß [önd my footnoteü] anotherß [änd my footnote2] line\r\nfinal line";
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$textlines = preg_split("/(\r\n|\r|\n)/", $content);
foreach($textlines as $line) {
    # check for footnotes
    if (preg_match("/\[.+?\]/", $line)) {
        $textrun = $section->addTextRun();
        $chunk_array=preg_split("/([\[\]])/", $line, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        foreach ($chunk_array as $chunk) {
            # open
            if ($chunk=="[") {
                $openit=true;
                $closeit=false;
                continue;
            }
            if ($chunk=="]") {
                $openit=false;
                $closeit=true;
                continue;
            }                           
            if ($openit) {
                $footnote = $textrun->addFootnote();
                $footnote->addText(htmlspecialchars($chunk));
            } else {
                $textrun->addText(htmlspecialchars(rtrim($chunk)));
            }
            #print $chunk."\n";
        }
    } else {
        $section->addText(htmlspecialchars($line));
    }
}
```